# Help needed in MySql Select Query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

Suppose a table has a Column "user_id" which is of integer type.

How to select a list of all the user_id except the minimum user_id  in MySql ???

The Except keyword is not working in MySql as in Ms Sql

actually my user_id selection is already based on a where clause like select user_id from table where ref_id=54 and i want to get all the user_id except the min one.plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for a solution like this..

here i will get each row except the row which have iUserID as min value

```
SELECT * FROM tbluser
WHERE tbluser.iUserID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(iUserID) FROM tbluser)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
WHERE user_id <> ANY (
  SELECT MIN(user_id) FROM table
);
```

Comment: actually my user_id selection is already based on a where clause like select user_id from table where ref_id=54  and i want to get all the user_id except the min one.plz help sorry for the incomplete question

Comment: Since the subselect returns only one value, you don't need `ANY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM TABLE WHERE USER_ID > (SELECT USER_ID FROM TABLE ORDER DESC TOP 1)
```

Comment: Since the question is "except one" I would say, it would be more correct to have `<>` in WHERE, not `>`, although the result of query execution is the same.